# breeze dropdown navbar not working in mobile view laravel

Tags: laravel, breeze

I install breeze in my laravel project. When i try to access menu in mobile view, it is not showing anything. Navigation bar works well in    normal computer view but nothing is showing in mobile view.

I have gone through the code but can not find any problem or solution to it

navigation.blade.php

blade view

```
<nav x-data="{ open: false }" class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100">
    <!-- Primary Navigation Menu -->
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
            <div class="flex">
                <!-- Logo -->
                

                <!-- Navigation Links -->
                @guest


            <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                    <x-nav-link :href="route('index')" :active="request()->routeIs('index')">
                        {{ __('HOME') }}
                    </x-nav-link>
                </div>
 <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                <x-nav-link :href="route('about')" :active="request()->routeIs('about')">
                    {{ __('ABOUT') }}
                </x-nav-link>
                </div>

    @endguest

            @auth
            <!-- Settings Dropdown -->
            <div class="hidden sm:flex sm:items-center sm:ml-6">
                <x-dropdown align="right" width="48">
                    <x-slot name="trigger">
                        <button class="flex items-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                            <div>{{ Auth::user()->firstname }}</div>

                            <div class="ml-1">
                                <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </x-slot>

                    <x-slot name="content">
                        <!-- Authentication -->
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <x-dropdown-link :href="route('slogout')"
                                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                this.closest('form').submit();">
                                {{ __('Log Out') }}
                            </x-dropdown-link>
                        </form>
                    </x-slot>
                  
 @endauth
                </x-dropdown>
            </div>

            <!-- Hamburger -->
            <div class="-mr-2 flex items-center sm:hidden">
                <button @click="open = ! open" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                    <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path :class="{'hidden': open, 'inline-flex': ! open }" class="inline-flex" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                        <path :class="{'hidden': ! open, 'inline-flex': open }" class="hidden" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Responsive Navigation Menu -->
    @guest


    <div :class="{'block': open, 'hidden': ! open}" class="hidden sm:hidden">
        <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
            <x-nav-link :href="route('index')" :active="request()->routeIs('index')">
                {{ __('HOME') }}
            </x-nav-link>
        </div>



    <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
        <x-nav-link :href="route('about')" :active="request()->routeIs('about')">
            {{ __('ABOUT') }}
        </x-nav-link>
        </div>


    
@endguest
        <!-- Responsive Settings Options -->
        @auth


        <div class="pt-4 pb-1 border-t border-gray-200">
            <div class="px-4">
                <div class="font-medium text-base text-gray-800">{{ Auth::user()->othernames }}</div>
                <div class="font-medium text-sm text-gray-500">{{ Auth::user()->email }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-3 space-y-1">
                <!-- Authentication -->
                 
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <x-responsive-nav-link :href="route('logout')"
                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                        this.closest('form').submit();">
                        {{ __('Log Out') }}
                    </x-responsive-nav-link>
                </form>
                                </div>
        </div>
    @endauth
    </div>
</nav>
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{config('app.name', 'OPAAM')}}</title>

        <meta name="keywords" content="rent, flats, rooms,apartments,house">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

           
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

        @livewireStyles
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
        @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    </head>
    
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">

            @include ('pages._header')

                 @include('layouts.navigation')



            <div class="space-y-2 lg:space-y-0 lg:space-x-4 mt-4">
                <div class="relative lg:inline-flex bg-gray-100 rounded-xl">
                    <x-state-dropdown />
                </div>

                <!-- Search -->
                {{-- <div class="relative flex lg:inline-flex items-center bg-gray-100 rounded-xl px-3 py-2">
                    <form method="GET" action="/">
                        @if (request('state'))
                            <input type="hidden" name="state" value="{{ request('state') }}">
                        @endif

                        <input type="text"
                               name="search"
                               placeholder="Find something"
                               class="bg-transparent placeholder-black font-semibold text-sm"
                               value="{{ request('search') }}"
                        >
                    </form>
                </div> --}}
            </div>



            <main>
                {{ $slot }}
            </main>
            @livewireScripts

           
            
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using larave 8.

Comment: did you solved this? im also experiencing the same thing but with the profile dropdown menu, i think it's the ```x-dropdown-link``` component, it flickers for me, it used to work and im also testing in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

@Eduardo Yes, i have solved the problem. My problem was using wrong component
for normal view = x-nav-link
for mobile view = x-responsive-nav-link